# kinect green light keeps freshing. Seems no driver

Tags: ros, kinect, driver, freenect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed freenect from

```
                sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-freenect-stack
```

and also blacklist gspca_kinect(I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)

But when I try the command

```
                roslaunch freenect_launch freenect.launch
```

It says that

```
                [ INFO] [1380174487.842752473]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
```

and then I try
lsusb

it shows me like

```
               Bus 002 Device 015: ID 045e:02c2 Microsoft Corp. 
               Bus 002 Device 016: ID 045e:02be Microsoft Corp. 
               Bus 002 Device 017: ID 045e:02bf Microsoft Corp.
```

These are kinect's and I could not find something like camera or others.

Could you please help me? Since for this Sept I could not even run kinect on Ubuntu
and I feel confused.

Thank you so much and I will wait for the reply.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/83391/kinect-green-light-keeps-freshing.-seems-no-driver/) by [Battery](https://answers.ros.org/users/7016/battery/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2013-09-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [brianaxelrod](https://answers.ros.org/users/7406/brianaxelrod/) on 2013-10-03**:
I'm having this problem too. Where you able to find a solution?

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-10-03**:
Does it work using openni_launch? I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with Hydro and not having any issues with my Kinects.

**Comment by [Battery](https://answers.ros.org/users/7016/battery/) on 2013-10-04**:
Do you mean that you can launch Kinect successfully? What is your version of Kinect?
Could you plz leave your email and we could discuss directly.

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-11-12**:
@brianaxelrod please post your comment as an answer in order to be able to mark this question properly as closed. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It turns out that it was the specific kinect. Changing the kinect seemed to fix it. I'll have another chance to use it on Tuesday or Thursday so I can grab some more information and test it. @Battery, how would i grab the version? feel free to email me at kinect-problems@mit.edu in the next 48hours.

---

Originally posted by [brianaxelrod](https://answers.ros.org/users/7406/brianaxelrod/) with karma: 16 on 2013-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Victor Gomez](https://answers.ros.org/users/12286/victor-gomez/) on 2014-02-20**:
Did you still use a Kinect for Windows or chaged for a Kinect for XBOX? I'm having the exact same problem with a Kinect for Windows 1517.

**Comment by [Victor Gomez](https://answers.ros.org/users/12286/victor-gomez/) on 2014-02-27**:
Any update, anyone?